# How to get an Externally-owned account (EOA) with ethers / hardhat

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

I'm testing a contract (contractA) in a hardhat project and I'm using `await ethers.getSigners();` in the test file and one of the signers to connect with the contract:

`const retVal = await contractA.connect(addr1).functionA();`

The contract always throws an error at the beginning of functionA because of the following test:

```
require(
        Address.isContract(addr_),
        "contractA: invalid address"
      );
```

is it possible to get an EOA from ethers or I'd better create a mock contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing an EOA with a contract, an EOA is not a contract and thats why your `require` fails, you need to create a mock contract that calls this other contract.

Comment: I know the difference between EOA and a contract, the mistake was in my question, sorry. I'm getting around on it with a mock contract.